# Request post method doesn't return valid response

Tags: python, python-requests, captcha

I am trying to work on a website that has simple captcha. Here's the [link](https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp).

**Steps:**

One is supposed to type a case number e.g. `200078510`, then type the numbers in the captcha, then click on `Search` button.

**Progress:**

I could solve the part of the captcha, but when trying to use the `POST` method in `requests` library, I didn't get a valid response. I got this string `حدث خطأ ما` , which means that `Something went wrong`. A successful response would have included the case number in the response e.g. `200078510`.

**Question:**

90% of the time myCaptcha is correct so the problem, I think, is with the POST request. Can anyone see what is wrong with my POST request?

I provide a working VBA example at the end, as additional info, in case that helps.

---

Here's the code that I could do till now:

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

sNumber = 'Number.png'
sTemp = 'Temp.png'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

def getCaptcha():
    response = requests.get("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/captcha/imgCaptcha.jsp")
    with open(sNumber, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        f.close()
    img = cv2.imread(sNumber)
    lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    upper = np.array([46, 46, 255])
    thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    thresh = 255 - thresh
    cv2.imwrite(sTemp, thresh)   
    img=Image.open(sTemp)
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    return text

myCaptcha = getCaptcha()
print(myCaptcha)

payload = {'txtCaseNo': '200078510', 'txtCaptcha2': myCaptcha, 'searchType': '0'}
r = requests.post("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/viewResults/validateCase.jsp", data=payload)
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```

I even tried using headers like that and the same problem

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

payload = {'txtCaseNo': '200078510', 'txtCaptcha2': myCaptcha, 'searchType': '0'}
r = requests.post("https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/viewResults/validateCase.jsp",headers = headers, data=payload)
```

Simply I need to be able to use the POST method of the requests package so as to be able to send the suitable arguments and then navigate to multiple sections that are related to the searched number.

---

#### Supplementary Information (Working example reference in VBA):

I have a working code in VBA for the entire process. The code navigates to a URL and enter a number and enter the numbers on captcha. Here's the code:

```
Public vCaptcha

Sub Test()
    Dim wsIndex As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, htmlData As New HTMLDocument, postCasePane As Object, oTables As Object, postTable As Object, postWrongSec As Object, strArg As String, xTemp As String, sTemp As String, r As Long, lr As Long, i As Long, ii As Long, vMAX As Long, cnt As Long
    Set wsIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
    For r = 2 To wsIndex.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If r Mod 10 = 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Save
        lr = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If wsIndex.Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo Skipper
sPoint:
        Application.StatusBar = "Case Number: " & wsIndex.Cells(r, 1).Value & " ------- Row " & r
        DecryptCaptcha
        strArg = "txtCaseNo=" & wsIndex.Cells(r, 1).Value & "&txtCaptcha2=" & vCaptcha & "&searchType=0"
        With http
            .Open "POST", "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/viewResults/validateCase.jsp", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .send strArg
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set postWrongSec = html.querySelector("span[lang='AR-KW']")
            If Not postWrongSec Is Nothing Then
                If postWrongSec.innerText = "ÚÝæÇ: ÑãÒ ÇáÍãÇíÉ ÛíÑ ÕÍíÍ !!!" Then
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    Debug.Print "Wrong Captcha " & cnt: GoTo sPoint
                End If
            End If
            Set postCasePane = html.querySelector("#caseViewPane span h4")
            If postCasePane Is Nothing Then wsData.Range("A" & lr).Value = wsIndex.Cells(r, 1).Value: wsData.Range("C" & lr).Value = "ÑÞã ÇáÞÖíÉ ÛíÑ ÕÍíÍ": GoTo Skipper
            .Open "POST", "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/viewResults/viewLastEvents.jsp", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
            Set html = Nothing: Set htmlData = Nothing
Skipper:
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Next r
    Application.StatusBar = Empty
    MsgBox "Done...", 64
End Sub
```

And this is the part the is responsible for the captcha

```
Private Sub DecryptCaptcha()
    Dim res, sDestFolder As String, strFile As String, sURL As String
    sDestFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    strFile = "Number.png"
    sURL = "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/captcha/imgCaptcha.jsp"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        res = .responseBody
    End With
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .write res
        .SaveToFile sDestFolder & strFile, 2
    End With
    vCaptcha = CleanNumber(ScriptFile(sDestFolder & strFile))
End Sub

Function ScriptFile(strImage As String) As String
    Dim wshShell As Object, sOutput As String, strCommand As String
    sOutput = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\OutputNumber.txt"
    strCommand = "Powershell.exe -File ""C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\ConvertImage.ps1"" " & strImage
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshShell.Run strCommand, 0, True
    ScriptFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sOutput).ReadAll
End Function

Function CleanNumber(ByVal strText As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        If .Test(strText) Then
            CleanNumber = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Replace(strText, vbNullString))
        Else
            CleanNumber = strText
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

And as for the powershell file these are the contents

```
$image=$args[0]
$desktop= (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'Desktop')
$imagefile=(Join-Path $desktop 'NumberNew.png')
$textfile=(Join-Path $desktop 'OutputNumber')

cd (Join-Path $desktop '\')
magick convert $image -resize 300x160 -density 300 -quality 100 $imagefile
magick convert $imagefile -negate -lat 300x160+40% -negate $imagefile
tesseract.exe $imagefile $textfile -l eng
```

Of course the code requires tesseract to be installed and also the imagemagick to deal and manipulate the image. The code is working in VBA but I would like to use python for that to improve my skills. Now I am stuck and have no more points of success. Thanks advanced for help.

Comment: I have this question which illustrates this question well (The code in the other question is in VBA) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243735/

Comment: is your `getCaptcha()` function working fine? does it get the right numbers?

Comment: Yes this part of getting the numbers on the captcha is working well. Not all the time get the right numbers but it works with 90% of success.